# Pass parameter to webmethod $http post

Tags: angularjs, ajax, webmethod

I need to pass parameter to the webmethod below. I have value Param which need to be passed to webmethod.

```
var param='test'
$http({
method:"POST",
url:'/sites/Demo/_layouts/15/demo/Demo.aspx/mywebmethod',   
data: JSON,
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
})
.then(function(data) 
{
$scope.Jobject = data.data.d;
});
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may pass `params` key for parameters or `data` key form body data which is not available in `GET` method

```
var params = {
  name: 'This is parameter query'
}
var data = {
  name: 'This is body data'
}
$http({
  method: 'POST',
  url: '/sites/Demo/_layouts/15/demo/Demo.aspx/mywebmethod',
  data: data,
  params: params
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    $scope.Jobject = response.data.d;
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

or simply use

```
$http.post('/sites/Demo/_layouts/15/demo/Demo.aspx/mywebmethod', data).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.Jobject = response.data.d;
      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$http.post`

```
$http.post('/sites/Demo/_layouts/15/demo/Demo.aspx/mywebmethod', params)
```

For more details check [official documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post)

Answer (score 0):

```
$http({
 method:"POST",
 url:'/sites/Demo/_layouts/15/demo/Demo.aspx/mywebmethod',   
 data: JSON,
 headers: {
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 params: {name: param}
})
.then(function(data) 
{
  $scope.Jobject = data.data.d;
});
```

assuming you want to send that `params` string as a `name`